# R - performance issue writing XML

Tags: xml, performance, r

I'm trying to write an XML file from a data frame in R, but I'm running into performance issues.

I have the following code to write the XML file, and it works fine for small data frames like in my example. However, my real data frame consists of more than 50,000 rows and 5 columns. This takes well **over 10 hours to process**.

How can I improve performance?

```
require(XML)
products <- c('A','B','C')
location <- c(1,2,3) 
var1 <- c(1,2,3)
var2 <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(products, location, var1, var2)

data = newXMLNode("data",attrs=c(guid="snapshot_data"))
data2 = newXMLNode("data",parent=data)
for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
for (i in 3:4) {
element = newXMLNode("element",attrs=c(guid=paste(colnames(df) [i],df[j,1],df[j,2],sep="_")),parent=data2)
name = newXMLNode("name", paste(colnames(df) [i],df[j,1],df[j,2],sep=" "), parent=element)
value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(period="year", unit="Pure"),parent=element)
orig = newXMLNode("orig", round(df[j,i]),parent=value)
processes = newXMLNode("processed",parent=value)
meta = newXMLNode("meta",parent=element)
ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="fs_items"),parent=meta)
value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=colnames(df) [i]),parent=ref)
ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="products"),parent=meta)
value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=as.character(df[j,1])),parent=ref)
ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="location"),parent=meta)
value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=as.character(df[j,2])),parent=ref)
 }
}

saveXML(data,file="test.xml")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues here that are slowing you down. First, your nested loop probably isn't helping you too much. You can get rid of that by reshaping your data frame:

```
require(XML)
require(reshape2)

products <- c('A','B','C')
location <- c(1,2,3) 
var1 <- c(1,2,3)
var2 <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(products, location, var1, var2)

df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = c("products", "location"))
df2[,sapply(df2, is.factor)] <- lapply(df2[,sapply(df2, is.factor)], as.character)

df2
  products location variable value
1        A        1     var1     1
2        B        2     var1     2
3        C        3     var1     3
4        A        1     var2     1
5        B        2     var2     2
6        C        3     var2     3
```

This way, each metric you want to include in your XML is lined up in its own separate column.

This would result in the following method for building your XML tree (wrapped in a function for benchmarking later):

```
xml2 <- function(...) {
  data = newXMLNode("data",attrs=c(guid="snapshot_data"))
  data2 = newXMLNode("data",parent=data)
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    element = newXMLNode("element",attrs=c(guid=paste(df2$variable[j],df2$products[j],df2$location[j],sep="_")),parent=data2)
    name = newXMLNode("name", paste(df2$variable[j],df2$products[j],df2$location[j],sep=" "), parent=element)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(period="year", unit="Pure"),parent=element)
    orig = newXMLNode("orig", round(df2$value[j]),parent=value)
    processes = newXMLNode("processed",parent=value)
    meta = newXMLNode("meta",parent=element)
    ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="fs_items"),parent=meta)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df2$variable[j]),parent=ref)
    ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="products"),parent=meta)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df2$products[j]),parent=ref)
    ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="location"),parent=meta)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df2$location[j]),parent=ref)
  }
  data2
}
```

Beyond that, you're needlessly calling the `as.character` function, and repeatedly calling the `round` and `paste` functions when you could just call those on your data frame beforehand:

```
df3 <- df2
df3$element <- paste(df3$variable,df3$products,df3$location, sep="_")
df3$name <- paste(df3$variable,df3$products,df3$location, sep=" ")
df3$value <- round(df3$value)
```

This results in:

```
xml3 <- function(...) {
  data = newXMLNode("data",attrs=c(guid="snapshot_data"))
  data2 = newXMLNode("data",parent=data)
  for (j in 1:nrow(df3)) {
    element = newXMLNode("element",attrs=c(guid=df3$element[j]), parent=data2)
    name = newXMLNode("name", df3$name[j], parent=element)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(period="year", unit="Pure"),parent=element)
    orig = newXMLNode("orig", df3$value[j],parent=value)
    processes = newXMLNode("processed",parent=value)
    meta = newXMLNode("meta",parent=element)
    ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="fs_items"),parent=meta)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df3$variable[j]),parent=ref)
    ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="products"),parent=meta)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df3$products[j]),parent=ref)
    ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="location"),parent=meta)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df3$location[j]),parent=ref)
  }
  data2
}
```

Finally, you can create children nodes within the call to `newXMLNode`:

```
xml4 <- function(...) {
  data = newXMLNode("data",attrs=c(guid="snapshot_data"))
  data2 = newXMLNode("data",parent=data)
  for (j in 1:nrow(df3)) {
    element = newXMLNode("element",attrs=c(guid=df3$element[j]), parent=data2,
      .children = 
        list(newXMLNode("name", df3$name[j]),
          newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(period="year", unit="Pure"),
            .children = list(newXMLNode("orig", df3$value[j]),
              newXMLNode("processed")))))
    meta = newXMLNode("meta",parent=element,
      .children = list(
        newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="fs_items"),
          .children = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df3$variable[j]))),
        newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="products"),
          .children = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df3$products[j]))),
        newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="location"),
          .children = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df3$location[j])))))
  }
  data2
}
```

So, if we take your original process:

```
xml1 <- function(...) {
data = newXMLNode("data",attrs=c(guid="snapshot_data"))
data2 = newXMLNode("data",parent=data)
for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (i in 3:4) {
    element = newXMLNode("element",attrs=c(guid=paste(colnames(df) [i],df[j,1],df[j,2],sep="_")),parent=data2)
    name = newXMLNode("name", paste(colnames(df) [i],df[j,1],df[j,2],sep=" "), parent=element)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(period="year", unit="Pure"),parent=element)
    orig = newXMLNode("orig", round(df[j,i]),parent=value)
    processes = newXMLNode("processed",parent=value)
    meta = newXMLNode("meta",parent=element)
    ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="fs_items"),parent=meta)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=colnames(df) [i]),parent=ref)
    ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="products"),parent=meta)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=as.character(df[j,1])),parent=ref)
    ref = newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="location"),parent=meta)
    value = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=as.character(df[j,2])),parent=ref)
  }
}
  data2
}
```

And benchmark it:

```
microbenchmark(xml1(), xml2(), xml3(), xml4())
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 xml1() 100.43712 100.97356 101.52694 102.28243 367.6518   100
 xml2()  99.38772 100.02676 100.63210 101.19588 373.8043   100
 xml3()  98.91923  99.67163 100.22482 100.92313 394.2360   100
 xml4()  82.09688  82.60983  83.02559  83.64807 367.6711   100
```

Reshaping your data frame and calling functions once on that data frame instead of repeatedly within your for-loop both help a (very) little bit, but your real time-saver is going to be assigning children to parents within the call to `newXMLNode`. It's still not going to be fast, but it should be faster than what you were doing.

**EDIT**

If you need even more speed, you can collapse your node creation a little more (assigning "meta" as a child of "element" within that first call to newXMLnode):

```
xml5 <- function(...) {
  data = newXMLNode("data",attrs=c(guid="snapshot_data"))
  data2 = newXMLNode("data",parent=data)
  for (j in 1:nrow(df3)) {
    element = newXMLNode("element",attrs=c(guid=df3$element[j]), parent=data2,
      .children = 
        list(newXMLNode("name", df3$name[j]),
          newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(period="year", unit="Pure"),
            .children = list(newXMLNode("orig", df3$value[j]),
              newXMLNode("processed"))),
          newXMLNode("meta",
            .children = list(
              newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="fs_items"),
                .children = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df3$variable[j]))),
              newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="products"),
                .children = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df3$products[j]))),
              newXMLNode("ref", attrs=c('source-guid'="location"),
                .children = newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(guid=df3$location[j])))))))
  }
  data2
}
```

Beyond that, however, you're probably going to need to re-evaluate the way you've chosen to structure your XML document itself. For example, if you included your "value" nodes as actual values within your "ref" nodes (right now the "ref" node only have attributes with no node value), you could eliminate three calls to newXMLNode for each iteration of the loop:

```
xml6 <- function(...) {
  data = newXMLNode("data",attrs=c(guid="snapshot_data"))
  data2 = newXMLNode("data",parent=data)
  for (j in 1:nrow(df3)) {
    element = newXMLNode("element",attrs=c(guid=df3$element[j]), parent=data2,
      .children = 
        list(newXMLNode("name", df3$name[j]),
          newXMLNode("value", attrs=c(period="year", unit="Pure"),
            .children = list(newXMLNode("orig", df3$value[j]),
              newXMLNode("processed"))),
          newXMLNode("meta",
            .children = list(
              newXMLNode("ref", df3$variable[j], attrs=c('source-guid'="fs_items")),
              newXMLNode("ref", df3$products[j], attrs=c('source-guid'="products")),
              newXMLNode("ref", df3$location[j], attrs=c('source-guid'="location"))
            ))))
  }
  data2
}
```

Simplifying the structure of the XML document gives you increased speed:

```
microbenchmark(xml1(), xml2(), xml3(), xml4(), xml5(), xml6())

Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 xml1() 99.66528 100.79417 101.09906 101.56140 393.4303   100
 xml2() 98.58393  99.68279  99.90569 100.64327 392.6561   100
 xml3() 98.26595  99.41217  99.65450 100.37495 363.4646   100
 xml4() 81.32157  82.33324  82.62350  82.96958 363.4569   100
 xml5() 78.89286  79.96670  80.14763  80.74278 346.1388   100
 xml6() 71.17018  72.05212  72.36548  72.81261 334.9638   100
```

That's still not going to reduce the run time from hours to minutes. If you really need the thing to run that quickly, I'd go with something other than R that can handle loops more quickly.

Comment: thanks, very good comments on needlessly calling function in the loop! Although significantly reducing the time (almost 20%, impressive!), this would still take more than 8 hours to process. I need to get this down to a matter of minutes, not hours. Perhaps R just isn't the right application to write the XML file (last part of a larger process)?

Comment: See edits above. If you really have that large a data frame and really need to convert the whole thing in minutes, I think R might be the wrong application for this problem.